# Hide Active Slide in `asNavFor` slider in Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

## Question

Is there a way to hide the currently-active slide from a slider in Slick Slider?

### Motivation

I am building a Featured Posts slider. One post will be featured prominently, while the remaining posts will feature as previews in a column on the side. A total of 5 posts will be shown at a time.

This is pretty easy to do with [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) (1.9.0) but it has one issue: the "remaining posts" section should *only* show the remaining posts and not the current post. So when a post is selected it should scroll out of view in the slider, and the featured post slider will change to use the slide at the same index.

### Description of the Action

Basically, the initial state should be:

Featured Slider: Slide 1 is visible, all others are hidden.
Remaining Slider: Slide 1 is hidden, Slides 2-5 are visible.

If I click on slide 2 from the Remaining Slider:

Featured Slider: Slide 2 is visible, all others are hidden.
Remaining Slider: Slide 2 slides out of view, Slide 3 becomes the new top post followed by (in order) 4, 5, 1.

### JS Fiddle

Here's the JS Fiddle I'm working on: https://jsfiddle.net/zak_rhm/Lks61ah7/71/

#### HTML

```
<div id="Large_Slider">
    <!-- Should only show one slide at a time. -->
    <article class="slide">
        <h2>Slide 1</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="slide">
        <h2>Slide 2</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="slide">
        <h2>Slide 3</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="slide">
        <h2>Slide 4</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="slide">
        <h2>Slide 5</h2>
    </article>
</div>
<ul id="Small_Slider">
    <!-- Should only show four slides at a time, never show the slide in #Large_Slider -->
    <li id="slide">Slide 1</li>
    <li id="slide">Slide 2</li>
    <li id="slide">Slide 3</li>
    <li id="slide">Slide 4</li>
    <li id="slide">Slide 5</li>
</ul>
```

#### JavaScript (jQuery)

```
var $slider_lg = $("#Large_Slider")
var $slider_sm = $("#Small_Slider")

$slider_lg.slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '#Small_Slider',
  dots: true,
  fade: true
});

$slider_sm.slick({
  arrows: false,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '#Large_Slider',
  focusOnSelect: true,
  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/kmsv5xn8/

I changed your HTML so that the "Small_Slider" section begins at #2 and each slide has a `data-sm-slide` attribute:

```
<ul id="Small_Slider" class="slick-slider">
  <li id="sm-slide-2" class="slide slide--sm" data-sm-slide="2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/0f9/333?text=Slide+2" alt="Slide 2" height="48" width="64" class="slide--sm__img" />
    <span class="slide--sm__title">Slide 2</span>
  </li>
  <li id="sm-slide-3" class="slide slide--sm" data-sm-slide="3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/f09/fff?text=Slide+3" alt="Slide 3" height="48" width="64" class="slide--sm__img" />
    <span class="slide--sm__title">Slide 3</span>
  </li>
  <li id="sm-slide-4" class="slide slide--sm" data-sm-slide="4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/f90/333?text=Slide+4" alt="Slide 4" height="48" width="64" class="slide--sm__img" />
    <span class="slide--sm__title">Slide 4</span>
  </li>
  <li id="sm-slide-5" class="slide slide--sm" data-sm-slide="5">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/90f/fff?text=Slide+5" alt="Slide 5" height="48" width="64" class="slide--sm__img" />
    <span class="slide--sm__title">Slide 5</span>
  </li>
  <li id="sm-slide-1" class="slide slide--sm" data-sm-slide="1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/09f/333?text=Slide+1" alt="Slide 1" height="48" width="64" class="slide--sm__img" />
    <span class="slide--sm__title">Slide 1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

That takes care of the initial offset, however to show the correct slides I disabled the `focusOnSelect: true` property and added an event listener instead:

```
$slider_sm.on("click", "li.slide", function() {
  var slideNo = $(this).attr("data-sm-slide") - 1;
  $slider_lg.slick("slickGoTo", slideNo);
})
```

The corresponding slide index is taken from the `data-*` attribute and updates the main carousel; because that uses the `asNavFor` property, Slick takes care of the rest.

Comment: That's brilliant! Works very well. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a style in .slick-current class

```
#Small_Slider .slick-current {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  width:0px !important;
  height: 0px !important;
}
```