# How to hide current slide in the slick slider nav?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm using the slick slider nav, but I want to hide the current slide in the nav slider.

Currently you can see the current slide image at the top, but you can also see that same image at the start of the nav slider. I want to hide this image though, so that the slider nav will only show the next images, not the current.

Any idea if this is possible?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/zYRENeV) for reference.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="main-slider">
                <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/76e/abstract-1-1174741.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/a31/colorful-umbrella-1176220.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/aaf/abstract-paper-free-photo-1175904.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/4d6/chugh-1171409.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/655/glass-abstract-1501217.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
             <div class="nav-slider">
                <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/76e/abstract-1-1174741.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/a31/colorful-umbrella-1176220.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/aaf/abstract-paper-free-photo-1175904.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/4d6/chugh-1171409.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/655/glass-abstract-1501217.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  // Gallery - Synced sliders
  $(".main-slider").slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: ".nav-slider",
  });
  // Gallery - Nav slider
  $(".nav-slider").slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: ".main-slider",
    dots: false,
    arrows: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide Active Slide in \`asNavFor\` slider in Slick Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60399571/hide-active-slide-in-asnavfor-slider-in-slick-slider)

Comment: This solution does not work for me as I'm pulling images from Wordpress, I can't manually changing the output html like they did.

Answer (score 0):

Slick adds the `slick-current` class to the current slide.

So just add this to your CSS style:

```css
.nav-slider .slick-current {
  display: none;
}
```